# Creating a generic Search Helper object for sending search criteria across Web API and using in repository where clauses

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, reflection, abstract-class

I am attempting to create a search helper that will use generics in C#. I want this to be the only parameter to my repository functions rather than having several params of lists.

**For example I want to replace the following types of methods:**

```
    GetProducts(List<int> categoryIds = null)
    "WHERE (@CategoryIds IS NULL OR p.CategoryId IN @CategoryIds)"

    GetCustomers(List<int> projectIds = null, List<string> zipCodes = null)
    "WHERE (@ProjectIds IS NULL OR proj.ID IN @ProjectIds)
     AND (@ZipCodes IS NULL OR c.ZipCode IN @ZipCodes)"
```

**with something like:**

```
GetProducts(FilterHelper filters)
GetCustomers(FilterHelper filters)
```

filters will somehow contain all of the information I need to do the WHERE clauses with Dapper.

Since I am using Web API I am trying to create a single DTO called Filter that can send information like this down to my Repository layer. Then have the repository layer handle the rest.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction on this? I am assuming I would use generics and possibly reflection?

Comment: One thing to consider is whether you want to use http Get or http Post for your web api action. If you have a complex object with many fields i would go with Post (which is your case). If you have very simple and only few search filters then i will go with Get.

Comment: What is FilterHelper?  Can you post that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into expression trees.  There is quite a good article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics/).

I've not really worked with them in much depth, so can't give much of an example i'm afraid, but hopefully this will provide a starting point for you.

If you're using entity framework, it might be a little easier as you can easily create generic functions passing predicates and expression trees.

A basic example...

Given the following entities:

```
public class Book : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You can write this function:

```
 public IList<T> GetList<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        // where Context is my DbContext
        IQueryable<T> query = this.Context.Set<T>();

        foreach (var navigationProperty in include)
        {
            query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
        }

        return query?.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
public List<Book> GetAllBooksWithAuthorWherePriceIsGreaterThan10()
    {
        return repo.GetList<Book>(b => b.Price > 10m, b => b.Author).ToList();
    }
```